# Buffer Underfollow and ignoring buffer message of ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, buffer

I just wanted change the volume of mpeg file so try just like this.

(The mpeg file is 20Mbps NTSC-HD file)

```
    ffmpeg -i <inputfile.mpg> -vcodec copy -filter:a "volume=+3dB" <output.mpg>
```

And I found many warnning message like this

```
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=38310 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=40351 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=42392 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=44433 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=46474 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=48515 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=1 bufi=1077 size=1152
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=50556 size=111232
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=317008 size=433920
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=319049 size=433920
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=319049 size=433920
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=321090 size=433920
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=321090 size=433920
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] buffer underflow st=0 bufi=323131 size=433920
[mpeg @ 00000000030c24c0] packet too large, ignoring buffer limits to mux it
```

I tried to increase buffer with -bufsize but it's same..
My first screen displays like this.

```
ffmpeg version N-82143-gbf14393 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'EST0511.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:19.02, start: 0.226944, bitrate: 20928 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20000 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
```

May I have any advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

If the output extension is `.mpg`, ffmpeg assumes it's a MPEG-1 Systems stream, which expects a mpeg1video stream, with the buffer size expected of that.

For MPEG-2 PS, use `-f dvd`

```
ffmpeg -i <inputfile.mpg> -vcodec copy -c:a mp2 -af "volume=+3dB" -f dvd <output.mpg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But when I try with your instruction, the the messages are same. And I found created one more stream "Data: dvd_nav_packet" .. I don't want change the properties. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution <sub>(maybe)</sub>

Try removing `-vcodec copy` and letting `ffmpeg` do what it wants to do.

```
ffmpeg -i '<INPUT FILE PATH>' -filter:a 'volume=+3dB' OUTPUT.mpg
```

---

I've just done

```
ffmpeg -i test.flv -filter:a 'volume=+3dB' OUTPUT.mpg
```

and it worked.